# Android. Upgrade database on startup

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm referring to SearchableDictionary v2 sample code in Adroid.
In this example, in the content provider, the database is destroyed and recreated when a new database version is detected with onUpgrade method.
But This method start only when search is invoked.
Now i'd like to have an onUpgrade invoked when the application is started for the first time after application upgrade.
So how can i have onUpgrade works in the main activity if the onUpgrade method is implemented in a different activity?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply create update method in your contentProvider as Barak suggested there you will only open and close db which will automatically trigger onupgrade Use contentResolver in mainActivity to call that method and done :)

Comment: on Upgrade method will be implemented in sqliteOpenHelper class not in activity class

Comment: I think the actual trigger is opening the database, but you have to do that for almsot any method contained in a normal dbHelper, so I guess, thinking about it, it's kinda moot.  Heck, you could create a method `update` where all you do is open and them immediately close the db and the upgrade would fire.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please give me an example, sorry but i'm still new with java-Android. And yes onUpgrade is implemented in OpenHelper... so how can i make a call?

Comment: @Luigi simply create update method in your contentProvider as Barak suggested there you will only open and close db which will automatically trigger onupgrade
Use contentResolver in mainActivity to call that method and done :)

Comment: Ok... ehm... but have you any examples about how to use contentResolver in mainActivity?